# Show that the sum of these four vectors is $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-explanation, cross-product

Four vectors are erected perpendicularly to the four faces of a general tetrahedron. Each
vector is pointing outwards and has a length equal to the area of the face. Show that the sum of these four vectors is 0.

Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be vectors representing the three edges starting from a fixed vertex. Express each of the four vectors in terms of $A, B$, and $C$, and show that their sum is the zero vector; do not introduce a coordinate system.

I was trying to:
let's call the four vectors $$v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$$

we know that:

$$\frac{AC \times BC}{2} = v_1$$

I was trying to express the other vectors but I would need a fourth edge to do that  using origin as edge we have

$$\frac{OC \times OA}{2} = v_2$$
$$\frac{OB \times OC}{2} = v_3$$
$$\frac{OA \times OB}{2} = v_4$$

hence:
$$s =\frac{AC \times BC}{2} + \frac{OC \times OA}{2}+ \frac{OB \times OC}{2} + \frac{OA \times OB}{2}$$

$$s = \frac{1}{2}((AC \times BC) + (C \times A) + (B \times C )+ (A \times B) )$$

$$s = \frac{1}{2}(((C-A) \times (C-B)) + (C \times A) + (B \times C )+ (A \times B) )$$

Comment: Why not follow your method all the way? Put one of the vertices at the origin, and let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be vectors from the origin to each of the remaining vertices?

Comment: @TedShifrin if  I change the D with an O is that the correct system?

Comment: I'm not checking your signs. I prefer to use my origin as the *tail* of the vectors, not the head. But if you're consistent, you can do it any way you want. And you need to express $AC$ and $BC$ in terms of vectors with their tails (heads) at $D$.

Comment: @TedShifrin then I assume we should use a x b = -b x a ?

Comment: Well, of course!

Comment: Note that $v_3$ is pointing inwards, not out, as requested in the problem. It should be $OB\times OC$

Comment: @Andrei that's correct

Comment: v1 is my problem in the proof

Comment: how can I expand $(C−A)×(C−B)$ ?

Comment: @Somos do you have the proof?

Comment: @Somos how would you prove it using cross product

Comment: $(OC-OA)\times(OC-OB)=OC\times OC-OA\times OC+OA\times OB-OC\times OB$. Note that the first term is $0$.

Comment: @Andrei I am unable to finish the proof after expanding

Comment: You have the wrong sign for the $ABC$ face. I've added the solution

Comment: Surely a symmetry argument (maybe a little fancier than the context) proves this. Namely, the relevant permutation group $S_n$, in its natural action on $\mathbb R^n$, has no non-zero fixed vectors... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these types of problems, you must carefully account for the direction of the vectors. Let's choose $ABC$ in such a way that they form a triangle going clockwise, and $O$ a point above the $ABC$ plane, like in the picture below:
[image]
We choose the convention that $XY$ is the vector with the origin in $X$ and the tip in $Y$. Then the sum of the areas multiplied by $2$ is
$$2S=OA\times OB+OB\times OC+OC\times OA-BC\times BA$$
It does not matter which vertex you choose in the last term (I choose $B$), the important part is to make sure that the cross product points outwards. The way I've made the choice, $BC\times BA$ points up, in the same side of the $ABC$ plane as $O$. That's why I've put a negative sign for the last term.

Now $$OB+BC=OC\\OB+BA=OA$$so $$BC\times BA=(OC-OB)\times(OA-OB)\\=OC\times OA-OB\times OA-OC\times OB+OB\times OB\\=OC\times OA+OA\times OB+OB\times OC$$
I've uses $a\times b=-b\times a$ for the terms with the negative sign, and $a\times a=0$ for the last term.

With this, $$2S=OA\times OB+OB\times OC+OC\times OA-(OC\times OA+OA\times OB+OB\times OC)=0$$

Comment: how do you know BC×BA was pointing towards O ?

Comment: I've made a sketch with the assumption in my first paragraph. I will attach the picture to my answer. I suggest you do the same, since it will help you keep the order of terms right.